# Modulo Operator on a set in Python

Tags: python, set, modulo

How do I use the modulo operator on a set of numbers?

```
if value > 2 and value % 2 == 0 or value % 3 == 0 or value % 5 == 0 or value % 7 == 0 or value % 11 == 0: 
    return False
```

How do I consolidate all those "or" statements into something more elegant like "`and value % set == 0`"?

Comment: It's not 'more elegant', but "something that works" :D

Comment: I wish there's some abstract algebra theorem for this in a single condition :P maybe worth to ask on math stackexchange

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I don't think so cause it's a kind of primality test. However, these tests are not worthwhile with only 5 numbers against which divisibility is to be tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `any(...)`:

```
value = 100

if value > 2 and (any(value % x == 0 for x in [2, 3, 5, 7, 11])):
    print(False)
```

Comment: I see that's a list. does order matter or could I have used a set?

Comment: @GlennBlakney: Give it a try - you can use any iterable that produces the numbers you want including a list, a set, a dict, a generator or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` which

> *Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable*

```
checks = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9}
if value > 2 and any(value % check == 0 for check in checks):
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

value = #define value here

def modulo():
    for number in numbers:
        if value > 2:
            if value % number == 0:
                return False

modulo()
```

Comment: note: you don't use your parameter in the function (but the global var directly)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Noted! Just edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would help to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are also answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def Fun(value):
    if value > 2 and any([value%x==0 for x in [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]]):
        return False
    return True
```